# How to make this query run faster?

Tags: mysql, select, summary

I have query like this:

```
    SELECT 
    `om_chapter`.`manganame` as `link`,
    (SELECT `manganame` FROM `om_manga` WHERE `Active` = '1' AND `om_manga`.`link` = `om_chapter`.`manganame` LIMIT 0,1) AS `manganame`,
    (SELECT `cover` FROM `om_manga` WHERE `Active` = '1' AND `om_manga`.`link` = `om_chapter`.`manganame` LIMIT 0,1) AS `cover`,
    (SELECT `othername` FROM `om_manga` WHERE `Active` = '1' AND `om_manga`.`link` = `om_chapter`.`manganame` LIMIT 0,1) AS `othername`
FROM `om_chapter`
WHERE 
    `Active` = '1' AND 
    (SELECT `Active` From `om_manga` WHERE `om_manga`.`link` = `om_chapter`.`manganame` LIMIT 0,1) AND 
    `id` IN ( SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `om_chapter` WHERE `Active` = '1' GROUP BY `manganame` )
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

So how can I make this query faster?

Here are my tables:

om_chapter:

```
id  | manganame     | chapter   | Active
-----------------------------------------
1   | naruto        | 1         | 1
2   | naruto        | 12        | 1
3   | naruto        | 22        | 1
4   | bleach        | 10        | 1
5   | bleach        | 15        | 1
6   | gents         | 1         | 1
7   | naruto        | 21        | 1
```

om_manga:

```
id  | othername | manganame     | cover     | Active
-----------------------------------------------------
1   | naruto    | naruto        | n.jpg     | 1
2   | bleach    | bleach        | b.jpg     | 1
4   | gents     | gents         | g.jpg     | 1
```

First thing i want form this query is to give me 10 last rows form om_chapter by grouping manganame and ordering by id.. i try to use a simple query by using group or even distinct but none of them give me the right result...

In a simple query with group or distinct, the result is like this:

```
id  | manganame     | chapter   | Active
-----------------------------------------
7   | prince        | 21        | 1
5   | gent          | 15        | 1
2   | naruto        | 12        | 1
1   | bleach        | 1         | 1
```

But i want this result:

```
id  | manganame     | chapter   | Active
-----------------------------------------
9   | gents         | 21        | 1
8   | bleach        | 21        | 1
7   | prince        | 21        | 1
6   | naruto        | 1         | 1
```

So i use this:

```
WHERE 
`Active` = '1' AND 
(SELECT `Active` From `om_manga` WHERE `om_manga`.`link` = `om_chapter`.`manganame` LIMIT 0,1) AND 
`id` IN ( SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `om_chapter` WHERE `Active` = '1' GROUP BY `manganame` )
```

And i use sub select in where because i want Active's field in om_manga's table be 1..

For the reset of sub select, i actually didn`t try join, but i will..!

Comment: Posting additional information about the table structures will help.  Like indices etc.

Comment: Wow. That's about eighty times more complicated than it needs to be. I don't have time to try and figure out what you're trying to accomplish, but you should look into JOIN statements (I think you want an INNER JOIN for this...). Basically, it will join together two tables and you can set the conditions for the join. I think it's faster than subqueries for the most part.

Comment: @kamal That query is almost certainly more complicated than need be, but it's difficult to offer a better solution without knowing *what you're trying to achieve*. What output should this query produce? Specifically, are you looking for results for each chapter of each manga, or just the highest-numbered chapter?

Comment: @danielrsmith I explained a litter bit in first post

Comment: @djacobson I want 10 last rows form om_chapter by grouping manganame(i explained in first post) and selecting one row form om_manga by equal manganame in both tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your intentions.. But here's one try:

```
SELECT c.`manganame` AS `link`
     , m.`manganame`
     , m.`cover`
     , m.`othername`
FROM 
     `om_manga` m 
     INNER JOIN `om_chapter` c 
     ON m.`link` = c.`manganame`
     INNER JOIN 
     ( SELECT `manganame`, MAX(`id`) AS `maxid` 
       FROM `om_chapter` 
       WHERE `Active` = '1' 
       GROUP BY `manganame` ) mx
     ON mx.`maxid` = c.`id`
ORDER BY c.`id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce a foreign key contstrain to the om_chapter table to account for the link from a manga to its corresponding chapters.

This is how I would conceptualize the problem.

```
A manga can have many chapters.  A chapter belongs to one manga.
```

Then I would alter the om_chapter table, to include a foreign key for the chapter to link to the manga.

```
ALTER TABLE om_Chapter (
ADD mangaID int references om_Manga (id)
)
```

And drop the manganame column as it is just redundant now

```
 ALTER TABLE om_Chapter (
 DROP COLUMN manganame
)
```

Your tables then could look like this.

om_manga:

```
id  | othername | manganame     | cover     | Active
-----------------------------------------------------
1   | naruto    | naruto        | n.jpg     | 1
2   | bleach    | bleach        | b.jpg     | 1
4   | gents     | gents         | g.jpg     | 1
```

om_chapter:

```
id  | chapter   | Active  | mangaID
-----------------------------------------
1   | 1         | 1       |  1
2   | 12        | 1       |  1
3   | 22        | 1       |  1
4   | 10        | 1       |  2
5   | 15        | 1       |  2
6   | 1         | 1       |  4
```

Finally you could query the tables like so

```
SELECT TOP 10 m.Manganame as link,
  m.Manganame,
  m.cover,
  m.othername,

FROM om_manga as m INNER JOIN
  om_chapter as c ON m.ID = c.mangaID

WHERE m.active = 1 AND c.active = 1
ORDER BY m.ID DESC
```

Comment: Actually i have this idea in my mind... i tried later! and thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple join?

```
SELECT om_chapter.manganame, cover, othername
FROM om_chapter
JOIN om_manga ON om_chapter.manganame = om_manga=manganame
WHERE om_chapter.Active = 1 AND om_manga.Active = 1
```

unless I'm misreading your version.

Comment: Looks like he wants one record per manga (see MAX(id) on chapter table...)

Answer (score 0):

Use a left outer join (and lose the sub-queries, and the back-quotes):

```
SELECT c.manganame AS link,
       m.manganame AS manganame,
       m.cover     AS cover,
       m.othername AS `othername
  FROM om_chapter    AS c
  LEFT JOIN om_manga AS m
    ON c.manganame = m.manganame
 WHERE c.Active = '1'
   AND c.id IN (SELECT MAX(o.id)
                  FROM om_chapter AS o
                 WHERE o.active = 1
                 GROUP BY o.manganame)
 ORDER BY c.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Were it my query, I'd probably select '`c.id AS id`' too.